# I cannot check my email by using javamailAPI program?

Tags: java

I used this code to connect to my Gmail account in java using javamail API  but i get an exception when i run it. I am able to access gmail.com in my network through a browser though.:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.Message;

public class Mailread {

public static void main(String args[])
{

    Properties prop=new Properties();
    prop.put("mail.pop3.host","pop.gmail.com" );
    prop.put("mail.pop3.port","995");
    prop.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable",true);

    Session session= Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);
    try
    {
    Store store=session.getStore("pop3s");
    store.connect("pop.gmail.com","myusername@gmail.com","password");
    Folder folder=store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    Message message=folder.getMessage(3);
    System.out.println(message.getMessageNumber());
    System.out.println(message.getFrom());



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.exit(0);

    }

  }

   }
```

Exception:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port:       pop.gmail.com, 995; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:211)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at MailPackage.Mailread.main(Mailread.java:32)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:329)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:112)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:264)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:207)
... 3 more
```

.................................................................................

Comment: Are you sure that GMail didn't shut down their POP interface?  Or maybe they were having a bit of lag?

Comment: In my account there is options for using pop and i enabled it. I also used an javamail API program using IMAP interface and i got the exception cannot connect to imap.gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Authneticator while connecting to gmail.

The below code should work for you

```
// Setup authentication, get session
Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties,
     new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           return new PasswordAuthentication(
              "manisha@gmail.com", "manisha123");
        }
     });

Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "*************@gmail.com","your_password");

Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();

System.out.println("Total Messages:- " + messageCount);

Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
System.out.println("------------------------------");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   System.out.println("Mail Subject:- " + messages[i].getSubject());      
}
```

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: I still get the same exception. couldnt connect to pop.gmail.com

Comment: no improvement . still getting the same exception. could it be that a firewall blocked connections to it.

Comment: which version of JDK you are using

Comment: If it is JDK you need to add -Djava.net.preferIPV4Stack=true argument while running... bcoz by default JDK7 uses IPV6 address format... If you are still getting the same error  then your firewall would be blocking the connection...

Comment: jdk version  1.6.0_24 I am working this code in netbeans

Comment: Then it seems your firewall is stopping the connection... I tried the same code and it is workin for me